# Strange Error with String in Scala 2.12.7

Tags: string, scala, mqtt

I'm facing a very strange error dealing with Strings in one of my Scala application which I cannot reason about! What I have is an Observer that looks like this:

```
class MqttObserver[String] extends Observer[String] {

  private val logger = Logger.of[MqttObserver[String]]

  override def onNext(elem: String): Future[Ack] = {
    logger.info(s"Got a message from Mqtt broker $elem")
    Continue
  }

  override def onError(ex: Throwable): Unit = {
    logger.error(s"Stream error happened ${ex.getMessage}")
  }

  override def onComplete(): Unit = {
    logger.info(s"Stream ended")
  }
}
```

I'm then calling the onNext(elem: String) from the

Here is the error:

```
[error]  found   : java.lang.String
[error]  required: String(in class MqttObservable)
[error]       mqttObserver.onNext(message.getPayload.toString)
```

This is how I make the call!

```
  val callback: MqttCallback = new MqttCallback {
    override def connectionLost(cause: Throwable): Unit = {
      logger.info(cause)
    }
    override def deliveryComplete(token: IMqttDeliveryToken): Unit = {

    }
    override def messageArrived(topic: Predef.String, message: MqttMessage): Unit = {
      mqttObserver.onNext(message.getPayload.toString) // FAILS HERE!!!!
      logger.info("Using Default Console Callback --> Receiving Data, Topic : %s, Message : %s".format(topic, message))
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178377/java-generics-the-type-parameter-string-is-hiding-the-type-string
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820133/the-type-parameter-g-is-hiding-the-type-g

Comment: And what is `mqttObserver` then? How did you instantiate it? I'd prefer not to reopen it only so it can be re-closed for lacking an [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
class MqttObserver[String] extends Observer[String]
```

with

```
class MqttObserver[S] extends Observer[S]
```

Otherwise type parameter `String` hides standard type `java.lang.String`.

Comment: Could you please explain why?

Comment: @sparkr Type parameter `String` hides standard type `java.lang.String`.

Comment: Is there another way to fix this? I cannot change the MqttObserver signature

Comment: @sparkr Names of type parameters are not part of the signature, they can be replaced arbitrarily. Just use some less confusing name (one which is not `String`).

Comment: @AndreyTyukin It's possible that `MqttObserver` is a third-party class.

Comment: @sparkr Here `message.getPayload.toString` you created standard Java string and you try to use it where `MqttObservable`'s type is expected (maybe it should be inferred). So don't. I can't say better since you didn't provide MCVE. What error is if you put `message.getPayload` there?

Comment: @sparkr What is the type of `mqttObserver`? I guess it should be `MqttObserver[...]`. So in `mqttObserver.onNext(???)` you should substitute something of the same type `...`

Comment: mqttObserver: MqttObserver[String]

Comment: @sparkr What is `String` in `mqttObserver: MqttObserver[String]`? Is it `java.lang.String`?

Comment: It is of type String = java.lang.String It's the one standard from the Scala library

Comment: @sparkr Weird. Prepare MCVE.